# Image in gui with gridlines convert to a textfile with N by M dimensions of the grid and the plotted points matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, text, graph, grid

I have a image in my gui with added gridlines. I need be able to to create and save a text file with the N by M dimensions of the graph containing the contents of each box in the grid.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. 
You have an image, then it is broken into equal pieces (`grids`) and then you want to write those parts of image into separate files. Is that you question?

Comment: I want to write the entire grid into a single text file. The file should include where the spaces are empty and where they are filled.

Comment: Save the grid as a NxM zero-matrix (you know the dimension of your grid). Consider each box in your grid as a index of the matrix. Initially all boxes are unclicked by the user and hence all indices are zero. But when user clicks on a box, that corresponding matrix index will be 1 and all others still 0. 
Once you get the matrix, you can just write it in a text file.
So basically the the text file will be a NxM matrix of 0s and 1s - representing the grid.

Comment: You can start by reading about `CurrentPoint` and `ButtonDownFcn` in [**Axes Properties**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html). 
To write a matrix to a file use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html).

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

## Main file

This should be the main *script*.

```
Grid_Size = [5 5];

Grid_Type = 1; % The group of the new clicked points.

% Initialize
Grid_Matrix = zeros(Grid_Size);
grid_h = []; % Grid image handle

fig_h = figure('Units', 'Normalized');

% Show your image
rgb = imread('peppers.png');
im_h = imshow(rgb);

% Shut off the 'HitTest' to keep the functionality of figure ButtonDownFcn
set(im_h, 'HitTest', 'Off');
hold on % Hold on for the overlaying grid image.

% Image normalized position
Image_Pos = get(ancestor(im_h, 'axes'), 'Position');
im_size = size(rgb(:,:,1));

% Set the Mouse click callback for the figure (to a script in this case)
set(fig_h, 'ButtonDownFcn', 'Mouse_Click');
```

## Mouse_Click.m

The *script* callback, I suggest script rather than function to avoid the complexity of *scope* and etc.

```
Clicked = fliplr((get(fig_h, 'CurrentPoint') - Image_Pos(1:2))./Image_Pos(3:4));

if ~sum(Clicked < 0) && ~sum(Clicked > 1) % If inside of the image is clicked

    % Find the corresponding matrix index
    ind = num2cell(ceil(Clicked.*Grid_Size));
    % and toggle that element
    if Grid_Matrix(ind{:}) == 0
        Grid_Matrix(ind{:}) = Grid_Type;
    else
        Grid_Matrix(ind{:}) = 0;
    end

    % Show the result to user
    delete(grid_h); % delete the previous grid image
    % resize the Grid Matrix to the image size
    Grid_Matrix_rs = imresize(flipud(Grid_Matrix), im_size, 'box');
    Grid_Matrix_rgb = label2rgb(Grid_Matrix_rs, 'spring', 'b');
    grid_h = imshow(Grid_Matrix_rgb);
    set(grid_h, 'HitTest', 'Off');
    set(grid_h, 'AlphaData', 0.3); % Show the grid image with an opacity

    % Write data to file after each update (user click)
    dlmwrite('GridBox.dat', flipud(Grid_Matrix));
end
```

Note that [`flipud`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) is used to flip the matrix to match the image indexing.

During clicking you can change `Grid_Type` (Using a UI or in command window) to another integer so that you get another color. However the previous colors might change, but finally all the same colors have the same index inside the `Grid_Matrix`.

You will get something like:

[image: Grided_UI]

Corresponding to this `Grid_Matrix`:

```
4,0,3,0,2
0,1,0,0,0
3,0,1,0,4
2,0,2,1,0
0,0,3,0,0
```

**To Read the result from file**

```
res = dlmread('GridBox.dat')
```

Comment: is there a way to change the color of the clicked grid squares and replicate it with other colors? And if so, lets say you make some red boxes with one type of togglebutton click or something on a gui, can you make the other colored grid boxes represent a different number on the matrix. ie, 1, 2, 3... etc